# Validation rule if checkbox is checked on "true"

Tags: validation-rule

Today I have to create a validation rule on an object:

one of it's field is a checkbox, and I want that if the checkbox is "true"

> then a specific user (called A) must complete all the phases of the
> object

(Example: object has a many months, if a checkbox is "true" than the users must complete all the months, otherwise he can step from a month to another)

Thank you in advance.

Edit: if the checkbox of a field of object "Opportunity" is "true", the user MUST follow in CHRONOLOGICAL ORDER all the steps defined by field "status"  (picklist with values: phase1, phase2, phase3, phase4)

Comment: Please clarify more on what should happen when the checkbox is true. It is not clear from the question

Comment: what are all the fields(specify with data types) should fill by the user when checkbox is true.

Comment: if checkbox=True in a field in object  Opportunity, the user MUST follow in chronological order all the steps  (field name: Status, defined by a picklist )

Comment: Can you explain the chronological order of status picklist in your case?

Comment: phase1, phase2, phase3, phase4

Comment: That means, when checkbox is true, user should fill the status field with phase1. Next time user tries to change the status value from phase1 to phase3/phase4, system shouldn't allow him to save the record. Am i correct?

Comment: yes, if checkbox is true the user must follow all the phases in chronologycal order, he can't jump for example from phase 1 to phase 4 without completing the previous phases

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?  You will need to use the `PRIORVALUE()` function, see [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_priorvalue.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation rule should be like below.

Replace the field API names (`Status1__c,Status_Order_check__c`) as per your org.

Here, I am checking current user(`$User.Alias ='aband'`) based on `Alias` because we can't able to refer the `Name` field in the validation rule.

```
    AND(Status_Order_check__c=true, $User.Alias ='aband',
    ISCHANGED(Status1__c),  
    OR(AND(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status1__c),""),
         OR(ISPICKVAL(Status1__c,"phase2"), 
            ISPICKVAL(Status1__c,"phase3"),
            ISPICKVAL(Status1__c,"phase4"))),   
      AND(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status1__c),"phase1"),NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status1__c,"phase2"))
          ),
      AND(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status1__c),"phase2"),NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status1__c,"phase3"))
         ),
      AND(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status1__c),"phase3"),NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status1__c,"phase4"))
         )
    )  
)
```

AND

> Returns a TRUE response if all values are true; returns a FALSE
> response if one or more values are false.
>
> Use the && (AND) function as an alternative to the operator.
>
> Use: AND(logical1,logical2,...) and replace logical1,logical2,... with
> the values that you want evaluated.

PRIORVALUE

> Returns the previous value of a field.
>
> Use: PRIORVALUE(field)

|| (OR)

> Evaluates if at least one of multiple values or expressions is true.
> Use: this operator as an alternative to the logical function OR.
>
> Use: (logical1) || (logical2) and replace any number of logical
> references with the values or expressions you want evaluated.

Comment: Thank you so much, the explanation is perfect, have a good day